# How to restrict element content inside a complexType with attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate XML with a help of an XSD.

Here is the sample of my XML:

```
<Cells 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation= "ImportCellsXSD.xsd">
    <Cell spread="2" row="128" column="51">p</Cell>  
    <Cell spread="0" row="10" column="1">ea</Cell>        
    <Cell spread="0" row="8" column="2">d</Cell>                  
</Cells>
```

And here is my XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Cells">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Cell" type="TCell" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>   

    <xs:complexType name="TCell">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Cell" type="TCellValidation" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="spread" type="TSpread" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="row" type="TRow" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="column" type="TColumn" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>    

    <xs:simpleType name="TCellValidation">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">       
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

`TSpread`, `TColumn` and `TRow` are just a validation of `minInclusive` and `maxInclusive`

When I'm trying to validate the xml i get this error trying to read the "p" , "ea" and "d"

> cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'Cell' cannot have character [children],
>   because the type's content type is element-only. [6] 
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Cell' is not complete.
>   One of '{Cell}' is expected. [6]

How can I define the content of `cell`? (p , ea and d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD is calling for `Cell` elements to be within `Cell` elements -- probably not what you want, and definitely not what your XML has.

Here is your XSD fixed to eliminate the above problem and validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Cells">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Cell" type="TCell" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>   

  <xs:complexType name="TCell">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="TCellValidation">
        <xs:attribute name="spread" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="row" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="column" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>    

  <xs:simpleType name="TCellValidation">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">       
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

(`TSpread`, `TColumn` and `TRow` are not defined in your posted XSD, so I stubbed them out as `xs:string`, but the principle remains the same.)

Comment: Thank you! It worked, the SimpleContent and the extension solved my problem.TSpread, TColumn and Trow were just  minimal validations